# Problema con flexbox(align-items)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola como están? Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de crear un simple sidebar con flexbox, importe dos iconos desde font awesome, los cuales funcionan a la perfección, el problema esta cuando hago hover sobre el icono de hamburguesa para que el menu se despliegue, los iconos se elevan hacia arriba, en el codigo tengo aplicada la propiedad align-items

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/*Menu Styles*/

.navbar {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.fa-bars {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #060A24;
}

.fa-bars:hover+.lista {
  display: block;
}

.lista {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 16px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 224px;
  background-color: #0000EC;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: ibm plex mono;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:400,500|IBM+Plex+Sans:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1ba5e8b5e2.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    <ul class="lista">
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">EPISODIOS</a></li>
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">NOSOTROS</a></li>
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">TÓPICOS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

para centrar los iconos dentro del sidebar, me arroja error tanto con center como con flex-end, con flex-start funciona a la perfección, no se que es lo que puede estar fallando, espero que alguien pueda explicarme el funcionamiento correcto, gracias.

Comment: Hola, veo que hay una vibración cuando pasas el _mouse_ por encima del icono, tal vez te sirva revisar esta respuesta [¿Por qué vibra al hacer hover al borde de cada icono?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/293842/77879)

Comment: Acabo de revisarlo y el error se debe a lo mismo, esta fallando por la propiedad align-items: center / flex-end, con flex-start esto no sucede, pero gracias por la observación.

Comment: Probaste usando: visibility: hidden; en .lista y visibility: visible; en .fa-bars:hover+.lista en lugar del display:block; y display: none; Ya que esto sucede por la posición <i> (.fa-bars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el `ul` está dentro del `nav` y forma parte del flexbox por lo que la altura inicial de 40px no se respeta al mostrarlo, la solución más sencilla sería sacar el `ul` del flujo del flexbox con una posición absoluta:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/*Menu Styles*/

.navbar {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.fa-bars {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #060A24;
}

.fa-bars:hover+.lista {
  display: block;
}

.lista {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 224px;
  background-color: #0000EC;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: ibm plex mono;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:400,500|IBM+Plex+Sans:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1ba5e8b5e2.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    <ul class="lista">
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">EPISODIOS</a></li>
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">NOSOTROS</a></li>
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
      <li class="elements"><a class="link" href="">TÓPICOS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, fue de mucha ayuda, el problema se soluciono.

Comment: Otra consulta, position absolute no se calcula respecto al elemento padre mas cercano con un position dado? En este caso como se estaria calculando, con respecto a quien? si navbar solo tiene un display, no tiene un position.

Comment: Como no hay ningún padre con position se posiciona respecto al `body`, en este caso funciona porque no hay nada más pero sería mejor que el `nav` tuviera un `position:relative` para asegurarse de que el menú se mantiene en su sitio